# How to add external Json as variables to shopify

Tags: shopify

In my online shop I want to show some more data about each product. I have managed to do this by adding an extra nodes to `settings_data.json` file. Like this:

```
{
  "current": {
    ...
    ...
    "7887193478": {    //Product ID
        "has-badge" => true,
        "show-image" => false
        ...
    },
    "7887193479": {    //Product ID
        "has-badge" => true,
        "show-image" => true
        ...
    },
  }
}
```

It is working and I am getting the data and showing it successfully.

> The good thing about this solution is the page load is very fast.

But the problem is when some one updates the theme setting it overrides the `settings_data.json` file. Is there any way that I can import this extra json settings separably into my Shopify?

> **Please do not advise me with Metadata App. Metadata app is very slow and I am not interested to use it.**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a snippet `products_data.liquid` (or any other name you want) that stores the information you need, that's separate from the theme settings file, and won't be overwritten. Here's an example:

```
{% assign "7887193478-has-badge"  = true %}
{% assign "7887193478-show-image" = false %}

{% assign "7887193479-has-badge"  = true %}
{% assign "7887193479-show-image" = true %}

...
```

Then you'll want to include it somewhere in there `theme.liquid` file, above where you'd be using it:

```
{% include "products_data" %}
```

The downside is that it's not as clean in terms of data entry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have roughly 500 lines of data (json array) and it will be more in the future. This solution works for 2-3 variables. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: This solution works for as many variables as you need. What makes this more difficult than your current solution?